# I want to use the parameter passed in function as variable

Tags: python, function

I am new in Python and programming 
in the below code,  I wish the "name" parameter is used as variable

no do not how to

I want to use the parameter of "name" to be used as "a1" .... ???

```
def frame_maker(name, color, r, c, pc):
    a1 = tkinter.Frame(mw)
    a1.grid(row=r, column=c)
    a1.config(background= color, width=70, height=70)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is not clear. Please be much more specific as to what you want to accomplish and what your difficulty is. Read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: No, you want the value of `name` to be used as a key in a dictionary with a fixed name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply pass the argument at the time of function call, they will be assigned respectively.

Function call can be as follows:

```
frame_maker(a1,color,r,c,pc)
```

else in the function definition, you can assign it to a variable

```
a1=name
```

Comment: my problem is value a1 keeps changing

Comment: every time with what ever value function is called, it is executed with the same value..

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going about this the wrong way. Don't use a `name` parameter at all. Instead return `a1` and capture it from the call.

```
def frame_maker(color, r, c, pc):
    a1 = ...
    return a1

name = frame_maker('red', 0, 0, 'foobar')
```

Comment: Yes, this sounds like the right answer, but it’s not clear from the question that this is what’s needed.

Comment: @quamrana Yeah, you're right. I'm voting to close the question as unclear.